# Rails Migration: How to increase INTEGER size by using ROR migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My contacts table number column is Integer type. Now I am planning to increase the limit.

Any one please let me know how can we increase limit by using ROR migration.

Comment: 8401905643 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4 change_colmn is not working

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `change_column` [migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) method

```
change_column :table_name, :table_column, :integer, limit: N
```

More information are also available in the [Rails migration guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns).