# Rails Deployment to Heroku Is Showing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment

I am newbie
need help please on showing what's wrong with my deployment to heroku.
here is the testing link on heroku click https://stableform4.herokuapp.com/
The problems are:

1. I can log in but can not create an enrollment.
2. on 'client new form' checkboxes are missing
3. When I click 'submit' it says "I am sorry, but something went wrong"

I don't know what to do to resolve this issue, please, is there anyone can help me solve this issue?

> here is my gemfile:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry'
  
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'

end
```

> here is my 'heroku logs'

```html
yoskakomba:~/workspace (master) $ heroku logs
2016-03-17T01:59:48.800895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-17T01:59:49.109588+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-03-17T01:59:49.109598+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:37193
2016-03-17T01:59:49.109600+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-03-17T01:59:49.109599+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-03-17T01:59:49.109601+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 01:59:49 +0000
2016-03-17T01:59:49.152469+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LoginsController#new as HTML
2016-03-17T01:59:49.164862+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_page_title.html.erb (0.3ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:49.165482+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered logins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.9ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:49.190211+00:00 app[web.1]:   Client Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-03-17T01:59:49.203241+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (35.4ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:49.204391+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.7ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:49.205755+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:49.206024+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 36.1ms | ActiveRecord: 10.7ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:49.207719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=46276eb3-6eaa-4e18-8260-2b51e7c4b709 fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=104ms status=200 bytes=5248
2016-03-17T01:59:54.692610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logout" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=91a7fe3b-0fc3-4dc5-a017-3b609a7bae68 fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=302 bytes=1119
2016-03-17T01:59:54.686439+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/logout" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 01:59:54 +0000
2016-03-17T01:59:54.689001+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LoginsController#destroy as HTML
2016-03-17T01:59:54.689700+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://stableform4.herokuapp.com/
2016-03-17T01:59:54.690247+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:55.215672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=e78735f7-914b-477f-adcc-ce83323db296 fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=4922
2016-03-17T01:59:55.202635+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 01:59:55 +0000
2016-03-17T01:59:55.204506+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LoginsController#new as HTML
2016-03-17T01:59:55.207610+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_page_title.html.erb (0.3ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:55.208417+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered logins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:55.211095+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.5ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:55.212567+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.4ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:55.213291+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2016-03-17T01:59:55.213486+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-03-17T02:02:09.647931+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by ariel.kakomba@gmail.com
2016-03-17T02:02:12.807089+00:00 heroku[run.1529]: Awaiting client
2016-03-17T02:02:12.841273+00:00 heroku[run.1529]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-03-17T02:02:13.097509+00:00 heroku[run.1529]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-17T02:02:22.198991+00:00 heroku[run.1529]: Process exited with status 0
2016-03-17T02:02:22.214176+00:00 heroku[run.1529]: State changed from up to complete
2016-03-17T02:04:00.656899+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=a18b4e0e-4970-4811-9bf4-f0d8f62e0f63 fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=4604
2016-03-17T02:04:00.648236+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 02:04:00 +0000
2016-03-17T02:04:00.650631+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LoginsController#new as HTML
2016-03-17T02:04:00.653352+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered logins/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:00.655566+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:00.652335+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_page_title.html.erb (0.0ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:00.655364+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.6ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:00.656716+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:00.656386+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:08.275043+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/login" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=c71dfcb4-465c-4070-aea7-59a572158f7d fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=91ms status=302 bytes=1058
2016-03-17T02:04:08.193729+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/login" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 02:04:08 +0000
2016-03-17T02:04:08.196792+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LoginsController#create as HTML
2016-03-17T02:04:08.201807+00:00 app[web.1]:   Client Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."email" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["email", "ariel.kakomba@gmail.com"]]
2016-03-17T02:04:08.196833+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"u9z0gLOM4sUnz3avEKbr0w6FIkl10mkyInOmB/Dlg6C3ZTJVnWWvdAeRA/Czs/8/ppzy58zoC6kX10mMQofhrA==", "email"=>"ariel.kakomba@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
2016-03-17T02:04:08.274341+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 77ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:08.273787+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://stableform4.herokuapp.com/enrollments
2016-03-17T02:04:08.577769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/enrollments" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=b97a0fa7-cee7-4533-a1a8-7dec6323bc90 fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=302 bytes=1226
2016-03-17T02:04:08.568413+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/enrollments" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 02:04:08 +0000
2016-03-17T02:04:08.572131+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by EnrollmentsController#index as HTML
2016-03-17T02:04:08.575119+00:00 app[web.1]:   Client Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-03-17T02:04:08.576385+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://stableform4.herokuapp.com/clients/1
2016-03-17T02:04:08.576653+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:08.576503+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :authorize_admin rendered or redirected
2016-03-17T02:04:08.895391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/clients/1" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=26b63272-8010-4409-90a1-7f8ee71ca1f2 fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=51ms status=200 bytes=5293
2016-03-17T02:04:08.848743+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/clients/1" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 02:04:08 +0000
2016-03-17T02:04:08.893270+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (2.6ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:08.851602+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ClientsController#show as HTML
2016-03-17T02:04:08.884658+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "enrollments" WHERE "enrollments"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 1]]
2016-03-17T02:04:08.893799+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:08.851684+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2016-03-17T02:04:08.854000+00:00 app[web.1]:   Client Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-03-17T02:04:08.879891+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_page_title.html.erb (0.0ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:08.889033+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered clients/show.html.erb within layouts/application (10.7ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:08.888057+00:00 app[web.1]:   Enrollment Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "enrollments".* FROM "enrollments" WHERE "enrollments"."client_id" = $1  ORDER BY "enrollments"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0  [["client_id", 1]]
2016-03-17T02:04:08.892373+00:00 app[web.1]:   Client Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-03-17T02:04:08.893569+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:08.894098+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 42ms (Views: 16.6ms | ActiveRecord: 6.8ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.625835+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/enrollments/new" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 02:04:13 +0000
2016-03-17T02:04:13.630925+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by EnrollmentsController#new as HTML
2016-03-17T02:04:13.697061+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_errors.html.erb (1.2ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.635323+00:00 app[web.1]:   Client Load (3.4ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-03-17T02:04:13.726775+00:00 app[web.1]:   Reference Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "references".* FROM "references"
2016-03-17T02:04:13.687583+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_page_title.html.erb (0.1ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.793988+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.1ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.794563+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.757761+00:00 app[web.1]:   Body Load (2.9ms)  SELECT "bodies".* FROM "bodies"
2016-03-17T02:04:13.781981+00:00 app[web.1]:   Health Load (6.7ms)  SELECT "healths".* FROM "healths"
2016-03-17T02:04:13.794876+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 164ms (Views: 78.4ms | ActiveRecord: 40.3ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.734171+00:00 app[web.1]:   Preference Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "preferences".* FROM "preferences"
2016-03-17T02:04:13.790775+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered enrollments/new.html.erb within layouts/application (104.7ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.790668+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered enrollments/_form.html.erb (101.6ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.794329+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
2016-03-17T02:04:13.796363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/enrollments/new" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=f969711c-1377-46e0-9f8f-a938fe9abe3a fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=181ms status=200 bytes=11068
2016-03-17T02:05:43.220836+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/enrollments" host=stableform4.herokuapp.com request_id=ffb38afc-19bf-4860-b470-d45d7dd390dc fwd="139.193.121.119" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=32ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-03-17T02:05:43.194475+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/enrollments" for 139.193.121.119 at 2016-03-17 02:05:43 +0000
2016-03-17T02:05:43.196504+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by EnrollmentsController#create as HTML
2016-03-17T02:05:43.196594+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1QcLKJHSbPsEOKCrUFQgK4Tg/sQat8yADgiwyabhvZDZvs39vzshSiRm1fTzQTTHLPkuaqONrhs7rF9CFIPfnA==", "enrollment"=>{"name"=>"Yosafat", "last_name"=>"Kakomba", "dob"=>"06/08/1982", "suburb"=>"Bekasi", "address"=>"Perum Vila Nusa Indah 2 Blok CC2/18 Jatiasih", "telephone"=>"622182403788", "post_code"=>"16969", "occupation"=>"", "exercise"=>"Never", "private_health_fund"=>"", "newsletter"=>"yes", "reference_ids"=>[""], "my_friend"=>"Yosafat Kakomba", "preference_ids"=>[""], "body_ids"=>[""], "health_ids"=>[""], "past_medical_history"=>"", "medication"=>"", "symptoms"=>"", "terms"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2016-03-17T02:05:43.198509+00:00 app[web.1]:   Client Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-03-17T02:05:43.217145+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
2016-03-17T02:05:43.221040+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-03-17T02:05:43.221405+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 8.5ms)
2016-03-17T02:05:43.222225+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-17T02:05:43.222234+00:00 app[web.1]: RangeError (622182403788 is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4):
2016-03-17T02:05:43.222235+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/enrollments_controller.rb:25:in `create'
2016-03-17T02:05:43.222258+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-17T02:05:43.222259+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me:
[image]

---

Error:

```
RangeError (622182403788 is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4):
2016-03-17T02:05:43.222235+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/enrollments_controller.rb:25:in `create'
2016-03-17T02:05:43.222258+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

This means you're trying you insert an integer (number) of `622182403788` into an `int` column that only allows `4` digits.

It looks like the error is caused by your `telephone` input:

```
"telephone"=>"622182403788"
```

The solution is either to [increase the `limit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004570/rails-migration-how-to-increase-integer-size-by-using-ror-migration) of the `telephone` column, or limit the `telephone` input to 4 numbers.

---

There are several things you should consider when dealing with Heroku:

1. **Use an alternative server to `WEBrick`** -- [We use `Puma`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#adding-puma-to-your-application) in production but don't have massive traffic. Our old devs used `Unicorn`, both of which provide concurrency.

If you use `puma`, the latest version kicks up errors if you're using Windows to develop the app. Our `Procfile` is as follows:

```
# Procfile
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb

#config/puma.rb
########################################

####################
#       Puma       #
####################

########################################

# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#adding-puma-to-your-application

if !ENV['RACK_ENV'] || ENV['RACK_ENV'] != 'development' #-> fixes "SIGTERM" error in Windows
    workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
    threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
    threads threads_count, threads_count
end

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

########################################
```

2. **`Heroku`'s logs are your best friend** - picking through the logs will tell you exactly what happened
3. **Use an "exceptions" gem** -- to replace the Rails standard error pages. We've developed [**`exception_handler`**](http://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler) to do this, and is now *extremely* popular:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You just need to add it to your `Gemfile` and you'll get access to the entire exception message / details in production:

```
#Gemfile
gem "exception_handler"
```

It's fully customizable and we've tested it thoroughly on Heroku -- it works with Rails 4 & 5.

It should give you much more to work with than the standard "Something went wrong" error.

---

**Update**

Sounds to me like you don't have any records in your `Reference` model / table.

The reason for this is that `Heroku` is *meant* to be a different "environment" than your development system. As such, the database is supposed to be completely separate.

You can read more about [setting up your databases in different environments here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior).

-

The important thing to consider is that because you're using *different* databases, your `production` db won't have any data in it.

You can test this by opening the [`heroku console`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#console):

```
# heroku run rails console
# refs = Reference.all
# -> should output all "Reference" records / objects
```

If the above does *not* show any objects, you'll have to populate them. There are two ways to do this:

- manually adding them to the system
- `rake db:seed`

If you're not bothered about retaining [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity), you'll be able to keep your `console` session open, and use the following to create some records:

```
# Reference.create attribute: "value", attribute_2: "value"
```

This will create the records manually for you.

The "correct" way to do this is to ["seed" the database](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data):

```
# db/seeds.rb
Reference.create name: "value", description: "value"
```

This will allow you to run `rake db:seed` from the heroku console:

```
# heroku run rails console
# rake db:seed
```

Comment: Thank you Richard for your help, I will apply this to fix the errors. How to solve when the 'checkboxes' in the form are missing when it's deployed to Heroku but the 'checkboxes' can be seen in c9.io.
http://imgur.com/tG4IzGM

Comment: Are those checkboxes built using `fields_for`?

Comment: I am using this code for checkboxes: 


'<strong>Reference: </strong><br>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes :reference_ids, Reference.all, :id, :name do |cb| %>
        <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text} %>
      <% end %>'
      
      
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Your code looks good -- the big test is, **have you got anything in your `Reference` model / table**? Remember when using Heroku, your data is completely wiped as you're using a "production" db.

Comment: How to check it if there is something missing in Heroku, and how to solve it? is it by going to Heroku run rails console and model.all? if I find something missing how to put it into database properly?
Thank you so much for your help